# Serial Port communication to PC troubleshooting

Tags: serial

## GOAL

The goal is to bridge a serial port measurement device into a USB PL2303 device.  Various degrees of success were observed and I hope the community can point me in the right direction in terms of troubleshooting, based on the data / observations below.

## SERIAL DATA DEVICE DESCRIPTION

A serial port measurement device (9600-8-N-1) has two outputs: each output sends a trio of bytes every second through:

- green wire: TTL
- blue wire: RS-232

The first byte indicates the qualify of the data and a good measurement is indicate with 0x80.

## PL2303 HXD Description

I have successfully connected the TTL wire to PL2303 devices and have run into unusual results wiring the blue RS-232 wire to a pink [PL2303](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/-H0AAOSwkXBdsnGw/s-l1600.jpg) and believe it to be a [HXD device](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pink-6Pin-PL2303HXD-USB-to-RS232-TTL-Cable-for-win-XP-VISTA-7-8-Android-bpHH/303636919013?hash=item46b22bb2e5:g:-H0AAOSwkXBdsnGw):

- Device Blue Wire:RS-232 <==> White Wire (PL2303 HXD)

HXD Description:

- Supports  RS-232 serial interface with Programmable baud rate from 75
  bps to 12 Mbps
- Supports  RS422/RS485 interface
- Extensive  flow control mechanism like adjustable high/low watermark
  level, automatic  hardware or software flow control, and inbound data
  buffer overflow detection
- This product is designed for laboratory, product  testing, low-cost
  MCU communications and other applications, there are four  lead,

HXD Wiring:

- Red +5 V
- Black GND
- White RXD
- Green TXD
- Yellow RTS
- Blue CTS

## DATA / OBSERVATIONS

The first 3 lines show RS-232 results.  0x80 (valid data) starts at the end of the 3rd line:

[image]

Said measurement serial-device has only 2 additional wires (power / ground) for a total of 4 wires.

Assuming that there is nothing wrong with measurement device, (it has been tested good with other RS-232 adapters).  I inherited PL2303 HXD and although I can lookup a  data sheet, I do not have the original data sheet and can not be certain I have the correct data sheet.

## QUESTIONS

**Does the PL2303 HXD need to be configured somehow to 9600-8-n-1 or does it somehow default to the configuration or detect the communication protocol?**  Any diagnostic questions or insight that would explain why the HXD does return good data are appreciated. Thank you

Perhaps the HXD model is not correct for RS-232 and the RS-232 design requirement should select a [PL2303-TA](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2PCS-PL2303TA-USB-TTL-to-RS232-Converter-Serial-Cable-module-for-win-XP-7-8-8-1/121920502340)?  Any clarification or insight that enables choosing the TA over the HXD (or vice versa) is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the in-line post header style connector on the pink PL2302 cable, I suspect that the cable uses TTL levels, not RS-232.  The TTL signal levels are inverted relative to RS-232.

I would expect a cable with RS-232 signal levels would use a DE-9 connector.

Comment: Well, when I connect long distances over 120 feet, I do use DB9 connector and 9 pin double shield cables. I do use MAX232 chip to convert 3V3/5V0 to shfit to +-12 volts signals. But that is overkill unless the other side insists on +1-12V. Perhaps the OP might like give us the links to your devices to clarify.

Comment: @PeterBennett  I believe that a DB9 connector indicates a RS-232 protocol, I would think that it is possible to use another physical connector for RS-232 communications.  I updated the OP with the electrical specs of the pink PL2303 (HXD).   Does it make sense to  try [PL2303TA found on eBay?](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2PCS-PL2303TA-USB-TTL-to-RS232-Converter-Serial-Cable-module-for-win-XP-7-8-8-1/121920502340)

Comment: @gatorback: It is certainly possible to use a connector other than DE-9 for RS-232 connections, but DE-9 is by far the most common. (and it is DE-0, not DB - the DB connector is much larger, and holds 25 pins.  The DB-25 connector was the standard RS-232 connector when I started in electronics in a previous century)

Comment: @gatorback - please really *read* this answer, you keep linking to what is clearly wrong sort of product with individual leads intended for Arduino/Pi/MCU projects, **if you want RS232 buy something with a 9 pin D-shape connector** then cut it off or better make an adapter cable.  And **shopping questions are off topic anyway**.

Comment: @PeterBennett. Thanks for the response / clarification.  I am trying to bridge an RJ11 terminated RS-232 device into a USB to serial cable.  I plan to terminate the USB to RS-232 Serial cable with RJ11 and bridge the two with a coupler.  Because 20+ units are to be built, choosing a design (PL2303 cables) will drive cost and labor outcomes